# What Maven artifact do I need to send a JMS message from POJO?

Tags: maven, jboss, jms

I need a program that sends a message to JMS Queue on JBoss 5.1 server. Basic scenario is that I connect to JBoss server by jndi, I lookup the ConnectionFactory and Queue, I produce the message and send it to the queue. Depending on different artifacts included, I get ClassNotFound for either NamingContextFactory, JBossConnectionFactory or even PointcutStats aop.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem? I'm looking for a simple configuration of maven artifacts (available on maven central or jboss nexus) that satisfies all the requirements. (Hint: currently I have jnp-client 4.2.2.GA, jbossall-client 4.2.2.GA, jboss 4.2.2.GA, jbossmq-client 4.0.2 and jms-api and they don't work ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example on configuring maven dependencies for JBoss 5.1 client http://www.javahelp.info/2010/01/27/get-the-right-dependencies-for-jboss-5-client-and-maven/

and 
http://www.developerscrappad.com/1490/java/java-ee/maven/building-and-deploying-java-ee-ear-with-maven-to-java-ee-application-server-part-4-deployment-to-jboss-5-x-jboss-6-x/